# group completion theorem of homology as Hopf algebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, hopf-algebras, homology, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $M$ be a topological monoid  with product $\mu$. Then $H_*(M)$ is a Hopf algebra with product $\mu_*$ and coproduct $\Delta_*$. The group-completion theorem by [McDuff-Segal, 1976](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01403148) gives that as a Pontrjagin ring, the localization 
$$H_*(M)[\pi_0M^{-1}]$$
is isomorphic  to 
$$
H_*(\Omega BM)$$
through the map on homology induced by the canonical map $M\to \Omega BM$. It is a ring isomorphism mapping $\mu_*$ to the product of $H_*(\Omega BM)$.

Question:

(1). What is the coproduct structure of the localization $$H_*(M)[\pi_0M^{-1}]$$
induced by $\Delta_*$?

(2). Is the above ring isomorphism $$ H_*(M)[\pi_0M^{-1}]\to H_*(\Omega BM)$$ also an isomorphism of coalgebras preserving the coproduct $\Delta_*$?

Comment: what is the antipode in $H_{\ast}(M)$ ? Is it not just a bialgebra ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. List item $H_*(M)[\pi _0(M)^{-1}]$ inherits its coalgebra structure from
   $H_*(M)$.  i.e., there is a unique coalgebra structure so that the localization
   becomes a map of coalgebras.  Concretely we "extend" the diagonal by declaring 
   elements of $\pi _0(M)^{-1}$ to be group-like.
2. List item Since the map $M\rightarrow \Omega BM$ is a map of spaces, it induces
   a map of coalgebras.  So you get an isomorphism of coalgebras.